# How to create thumnail navigation which is swipe enabled?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, navigation, swipe, swipe-gesture

I want to create a thumbnail navigation type of stuff which works as equivalent to ROYAL SLIDER thumbnail navigation as [here](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/gallery/)

it swipe enabled I'm using angular i tried using angular-gesture to achieve the same but its not adjusting with the device width you can see my implementation [here](http://www.webashlar.com/Demos/swipeTabs/#/). when swiped will navigate, i tried creating 3 > 3 > 2 thumbs but there is empty space and it should run on mobile devices.

Please help or guide me what can be done further

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that all you need are the `ng-swipe-left` and `ng-swipe-right` directives.  And then you can just build a simple carousel but have it change by doing `<div ng-swipe-left="goToNext()" ng-swipe-right="goToPrevious()"></div>` or something to that effect.  The docs are [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/docs/api/ngTouch.directive:ngSwipeLeft)

Comment: @tennisgent thanks for your comment i have implemented ng-swipe-left and right bur the problems lies in the layout display adapting to all devices